# Restart Service on termination

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a service for my app which connects to the server and checks for new posts. The issue is that when the app is removed from the "Recent Apps" list or when it is force closed, it gets terminated, otherwise it works fine. Is there any way in which I can restart the service again? e.g. Any broadcast which i can listen for? I've already added BootCompleteReceiver.

**Here's the code:**

### PostCheckService.java

```
package com.royal.bikers;

import static com.royal.bikers.resources.Constants.KEY_DATA;
import static com.royal.bikers.resources.Constants.KEY_ERROR;
import static com.royal.bikers.resources.Constants.KEY_MSG;
import static com.royal.bikers.resources.Constants.KEY_SIZE;
import static com.royal.bikers.resources.Constants.URL_EVENT;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.royal.bikers.resources.Functions;
import com.royal.bikers.resources.JSONParserForSearch;

public class PostsCheckService extends Service {

    private Timer timer;
    int newsize, diff, oldsize;
    private Functions functions = new Functions();
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;

    private TimerTask updateTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("TASK", "Checking for new posts");
            JSONParserForSearch jParser = new JSONParserForSearch();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL_EVENT);
            try {
                if (functions.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                    if (functions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {
                        Log.i("json log", "JSON RECEIVED");
                        String message = json.getString(KEY_MSG);
                        if (json.getInt(KEY_ERROR) == 0) {
                            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA);
                            newsize = data.length();
                            oldsize = functions.getSharedPrefrences(
                                    getApplicationContext(), KEY_SIZE);
                            if (newsize > oldsize) {
                                diff = newsize - oldsize;
                                Intent toSearch = new Intent(getApplication(),
                                        SearchActivity.class);
                                toSearch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                functions.putSharedPrefrences(
                                        getApplicationContext(), KEY_SIZE,
                                        newsize);
                                if (diff == 1) {

                                    showNotification("One New Event",
                                            "Tap to see new event",
                                            R.drawable.ic_notification,
                                            toSearch);
                                } else {
                                    showNotification(String.valueOf(diff)
                                            + " New Events",
                                            "Tap to see new events",
                                            R.drawable.ic_notification,
                                            toSearch);
                                }
                                Log.i("NEW POST", String.valueOf(diff));
                                oldsize = newsize;
                                functions.putSharedPrefrences(
                                        getApplicationContext(), KEY_SIZE,
                                        newsize);
                            } else if (newsize < oldsize) {
                                oldsize = newsize;
                                Log.i("Size Reduced By",
                                        String.valueOf(oldsize - newsize));
                                functions.putSharedPrefrences(
                                        getApplicationContext(), KEY_SIZE,
                                        newsize);
                            } else {

                                Log.i("NEW POST", "NONE");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e("ERROR", message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Not Logged In");
                        mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();
                        Intent toLogin = new Intent(getApplication(),
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        toLogin.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        showNotificationNoSound("Login Required",
                                "Tap to login into Royal Bikers",
                                R.drawable.ic_notification, toLogin);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Not Connected");

                    mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("TASK", "Service creating");

        timer = new Timer("NewPostTimer");
        timer.schedule(updateTask, 1000L, 10 * 1000L);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("TASK", "Service destroying");

        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String subtitle, int icon,
            Intent resultIntent) {
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent pendingResultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(subtitle).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingResultIntent).setSound(soundUri)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();
        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();
        mNotifyMgr.notify(0, mBuilder);
    }

    public void showNotificationNoSound(String title, String subtitle,
            int icon, Intent resultIntent) {

        PendingIntent pendingResultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(subtitle).setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingResultIntent).setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.cancelAll();
        mNotifyMgr.notify(0, mBuilder);
    }
}
```

### BootCompleteReceiver.java

```
package com.royal.bikers.resources;

import com.royal.bikers.PostsCheckService;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, PostsCheckService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

### Service and Reciever in Android Manifest

```
<service
            android:name="com.royal.bikers.PostsCheckService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.royal.bikers.PostsCheckService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.royal.bikers.resources.BootCompletedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I tried `onStartCommand()` with `START_STICKY` in `return` statement, but it didn't help. But still, if you can guide me to correct implementation of `onStartCommand()`, I'll be greatful.

Comment: Not sure why removing the app from 'Recent' should terminate the `Service` unless your main `Activity` stops it at some point. As for your app being @Force closed'...do you mean if the user goes to Settings -> Apps and manually stops the app? If so then depending on Android version there is no way to automatically start any app component - the user must actually launch your app again.

Comment: Killing the app from any external app like Advanced Task Killer is taken as a Force Close, i was talking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** poll for new posts every 10 seconds in the background, unless the user specifically asked for that polling frequency. That will drain the user's battery very quickly. Polling every 10 *minutes* might be more than the user wants.

Then, do **not** use `Timer` for background polling. Use `AlarmManager` with an `IntentService`, so your app can be shut down in between polling operations. This will have a side benefit of allowing your app to continue to get control even after its process is terminated by other reasons (e.g., user swiping the app out of the recent-tasks list).

Comment: I put 10 seconds just for checking if its working or not, otherwise i plan to put 1 hr as the interval.

Comment: @Chipset: That is all the more reason to use `AlarmManager`. It is highly unlikely that your process will still be around after an hour, even if the user does not swipe it out of the recent-tasks list.

Comment: So `AlarmManager` will automatically start my service, then do the task and close it after its done?

Comment: @Chipset: `AlarmManager` can start the service. An `IntentService` automatically shuts down when its work is finished.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, it is really an honour for noobs like me to receive help from greats like you. Thanks a lot, its working just the way i wanted. :)